# How to pass a JavaScript array into an inline function call generated by PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have build a dynamic list from an array and must print the onclick event inline, I don't know of anyway other way to do this.

```
<?php

$dataArray = $_POST['dataArray']; // This is a valid array

ECHO '<div id="colorSelectorBox">';

for ($btn = 0; $btn < sizeof($dataArray); $btn++){
    ECHO '<div class="btn-group">
              <button onclick="buildGroupList("'.$dataArray.'")">' .$dataArray[$btn].'</button>
              <button><div ..Stuff..></div></button>
          </div><br>'; 
}
ECHO '</div>';

?>
```

The problem is that the JavaScript function `buildGroupList()` does not receive an array from this instead the line looks like this in my developer tool:

```
onclick="buildGroupList(Array)"
```

**How can I pass in an array of values through to JavaScript?**

OR

**How can I re-write this so that the call is not inline?**

Comment: I don't understand. Where would that go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are trying to print the array as if automagically transforms itself into javascript array, that is, a string of its values separated by a comma (that is what it needs to output to the html, something the browser understands).

For that you need [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

> string implode ( string $glue , array $pieces )
>
> Join array elements with a $glue string.

```
ECHO "<div class=\"btn-group\">
    <button onclick=\"buildGroupList(['".implode("','",$dataArray)."'])\">" .$dataArray[$btn]."</button>
         <button><div ..Stuff..></div></button>
    </div><br>";
```

It takes every element in the array and puts $glue string between every one of them. The end result looks like this:

```
//let's assume this is your array in PHP
<?php
    $dataArray = array('one','two','three');
?>

<!-- then your HTML looks like this -->
<button onclick="buildGroupList(['one','two','three'])">...</button>
```

Remember that PHP and Javascript don't know each other.

Comment: Didn't work. The JavaScript function takes an array as its parameter, not a list of comma separated strings.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still having trouble but this might be an issue with the single and double quotes

Comment: use double quotes in PHP so you can escape the ones needed in the HTML with a "\" as i did above, the "\" won't show in the HTML.

Answer (score 3):

The shortest answer is: use json_encode() which will convert the array to a json string, but it's not good practice anyway.

Comment: I'm having a hard time converting the result into an array once it's in JS